# Rails Devise can't delete user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In development I am able to delete accounts, but in production it won't allow me.
I even tried to delete users from the console, but I get the follow errors.

```
Loading production environment (Rails 5.2.4.1)
irb(main):001:0> User.find_by(email: "XXX@protonmail.com")
D, [2020-02-13T19:00:27.815025 #4] DEBUG -- :    (4.6ms)  SET NAMES utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin,  @@SESSION.sql_mode = CONCAT(CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',STRICT_ALL_TABLES'), ',NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'),  @@SESSION.sql_auto_is_null = 0, @@SESSION.wait_timeout = 2147483
D, [2020-02-13T19:00:27.830307 #4] DEBUG -- :   User Load (1.5ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = 'XXX@protonmail.com' LIMIT 1
=> #<User id: 4706, email: "XXX@protonmail.com", created_at: "2020-01-08 23:46:23", updated_at: "2020-02-13 03:06:56", current_profile: 4030, admin: nil, mod: nil, banned: nil, polonly: nil>
irb(main):002:0> User.find_by(email: "XXX@protonmail.com").delete
D, [2020-02-13T19:00:30.525546 #4] DEBUG -- :   User Load (1.7ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = 'XXX@protonmail.com' LIMIT 1
D, [2020-02-13T19:00:30.534763 #4] DEBUG -- :   User Destroy (7.6ms)  DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 4706
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`website`.`profiles`, CONSTRAINT `fk_rails_e424190865` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)): DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 4706
    from (irb):2
```

User MODEL

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  after_create :skip_conf!
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable,
         :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable
  has_many :profiles

end
```

Profile MODEL

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  validates :username, uniqueness: true, presence: true
  belongs_to :user
  has_one_attached :avatar
  has_many :posts
  has_many :votes
  has_many :activities
  has_many :comments
end
```

Comment: did you ever get this fixed?

Comment: no, I could never delete it. instead I found some info on how to disable a devise account, and used that instead.

Comment: Ok, well one trick to use if you are in this situation again, or want to go back and fix this one .  When you run your rails server run it in production mode, then you will get an error output that may give more information. `rails s -e production`  it may help

Answer (score 0):

There is foreign key constraint of database which is preventing the delete of User. To reproduce it in your local setup, create User and create Profiles for that User and then try to delete the user, it should fail. 
To fix this, add **on_delete: :cascade** to your foreign key constraint in database migration of creating profile.

```
add_foreign_key :profiles, :users, on_delete: :cascade
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the records related to that user, otherwise. as the error says, `a foreign key constraint fails`.

Adding `:dependent => :destroy` should fix it

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  after_create :skip_conf!
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable,
     :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable
  has_many :profiles, :dependent => :destroy

end
```